# Need help in adding a iframe within a page in pyrocms

Tags: wordpress, drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg, pyrocms

As of now i'm using pyrocms for my projects. But the question is applicable to all cms which use an editor/WYSIWYG/fckeditor to update contents.

Thing is im having an iframe, say facebook like button. I couldn embed it in a page as it simply renders the code as such in the output page. But if i use the same in my footer html page, it's working fine. is there any way to overcome this rather than writing a plugin/widget that gets the info and render it?

Thanks 
goG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-eabled XSS support for modules but pages is a module that should not be XSS filtered (as it has no frontend data input anyway).

Open up the modules DB table and set skip_xss to 1. Then run:

> sudo rm -rf system/pyrocms/cache/module_m/

that will clear the cache and you'll find iframes are not removed anymore.